Microsoft Excel: Highlight decimal higher than .00
I am trying to highlight a cell based on the point decimal value. I understand how to highlight the point decimal with a MOD function but exclude a full value.
The data is quite simply based on dividing 2 cells, which results in a value X.XX
However when applying the MOD function in conditional formatting, I get full values as x.00
So I would like to highlight a cell ONLY when the decimal is greater than .00
I.e.
1.00 = don't highlight
1.01 to 1.99 = highlight
2.00 = don't highlight
2.01 to 2.99 = highlight
Etc.
Etc.

I would like to highlight the cell with a conditional formatting colour if it is possible - so 1.00 no highlight - 1.01 highlight in a colour.

I believe you want INT(), so something like: =INT(B1)=B1

For two decimal places, =INT(B1)=B1 might worlk, but note that numbers are not necessarily stored as they appear. For example, 1/3 = 0.333... ,but 1/3 * 3 = 1 and 0.333... * 3 = 0.999... (mathematically, they're equivalent, but in Excel, they might not be). Use a delta when checking equivalence to allow for such storage and rounding differences.

This MOD formulation should work : =MOD(A1,1)>0.


Due to internal storage and rounding, you might want to change that to something like  =MOD(A1,1)>0.0001, to allow for differences when a number is translated from binary to decimal, or due to limitations in  storage (e.g., 1/3 * 3 = 1, but in some machine calculations, might be expressed as 0.999...).

@DrMoishePippik: I tried just now, and my formulation worked for 1.000001 and 1.999999.

yes, calculations are now carried to greater f.p. precision, and there are rounding algorithms built into excel and math processing units to help, but ultimately, there are differences. In AssertEquals, https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.8/org/junit/Assert.html, for example, a delta may be used to specify allowed differences considered equal.

A variant that might be useful:
=INT(100*(A1-INT(A1)))
will give you the two first decimals,
i.e. 00 for numbers that are "close enough" to being integers.
So color cells when =( fill_in_formula_from_above )!=0
Change 100 to "any" higher power of ten to have the same amount of more digits accounted for.
Note that the limitations of floating point numbers apply here.

Just to update that I found the solution to it thanks to yours and some finance heads help :)
I used 3 conditional formating to make it work:

to remove the .00 but keep .01 to .99
=A1=INT(A1) --> Then go to format cell --> Number tab --> Custom --> type the following instead of standard:  #0_.0;;0._0;@

to highlight cell value lower than 0 i simply took the formating cell value < 1 and choose a colour

finally to highlight cell value with point decimal between .01 and .99 but not full value (1.00 - 2.00 - 45.00 - etc) I used MOD function as
=MOD(A1;1)<>0


This result in the following
1.17 = highlighted in yellow
1 = not highlighted
2.33 = highlighted in yellow
45 = Not highlighted
0.85 = Highlighted in Red
Etc
Etc
Thanks all again
